# Why does this expression result in `ReferenceError`?

Tags: javascript

Why does incrementing the same thing behave differently when I reference it via a variable?

```
function f() {
    return {};
}

let x = {};
x++; // OK
(f())++ // ReferenceError
```

Comment: `x++` makes no sense. You can't add to an object.

Comment: `++` can only be used on something you can assign to, since `x++` is equivalent to `x = x + 1`. You can't assign to a function call.

Comment: Unsure what you expect this code to do.

Comment: @Barmar `let x = {}; console.log(x++) // logs NaN `

Comment: @SuperStormer I expect the second-to-last line and the last line to do the same thing. But one sets the obect to undefined and evals to `NaN` and the other just `ReferenceError`s. Why the difference? How?

Comment: Right, it returns `NaN` because it makes no sense.

Comment: This is because as long as f() is terminated and as the value is not assigned to any left hand side, the execution context of the function is discarded and then the reference goes away.
If you instead do let y = f(); then you can do y++ as y is a valid reference and so a valid left hand side for the ++ operator.

Comment: It's syntactically valid because syntax doesn't care what the value of `x` is.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is due to that when js is evaluating the expression it starts by checking if the left hand side is convertible to a number and by quirkyness an object is converted to Nan whereas a function is is not and js throws an exception when trying to convert it before it is evaluated.
See also here:
https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-postfix-increment-operator

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't answer the question. I asked why `(f())++ ` is reference error but assigning the result of `f()` to an intermediate variable and then doing the postfix increment makes the problem go away.

Answer (score -2):

This whole code doesn't make any sense. You cannot increment a object.

Comment: `let x = {}; console.log(x++)` logs "NaN" and sets `x` to `undefined`